How to specify --trusted-host for pip in bazel build
I inherited a project which is using a bazel build. When doing the build it is trying to load dependencies and running commands similar to this:
command: C:/users/<username>/bazel<username>/tiijebj4/external/python_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/python.exe -m python.private.pypi.whl_installer.wheel_installer --requirement "scipy==1.13.1     --hash=sha256:0173674 ... etc ... --extra_pip_args "{"arg":[]}" --pip_data_exclude "{"arg":[]}" --environment "{"arg":{}}"

This command fails with this error:
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/scipy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/scipy/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)'))) - skipping

This is normal for pip in our environment to have issues with SSL for pypi.org and normally I workaround this by specifying parameters to pip along the lines of --trusted-host pypi.org
But I have no idea how to do something like this for the python used in bazel build. Apparently it does not care about pip.conf or pip.ini.
Based on the command the build is running apparently there is an argument --extra_pip_args which is probably what I need but I have no idea where and how to specify this as I know nothing about bazel and what I read about it so far seems massively counter intuitive and confusing.
Can someone show me exact syntax of what to put in WORKSPACE file to have those --extra_pip_args passed to whatever pip is used by bazel?
Or maybe there is a different workaround for this problem?

Can you pass environment variables? You can pass PIP_TRUSTED_HOST env var. See the docs and examples.

That did not work either and my understanding is that bazel build is using "hermetic python", the whole point of which is to disable an ability to influence anything via environment variables. I think the solution should be making some changes to workspace.
